# While adding new set items to a list , the order is not consistent

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I read ip addresses from a file and insert them to a set along with bool value 'False'. I use 'add' function.
Then I insert the set into a list.
example for list I want to get :
 [{1.2.3.5,False},{10.10.10.1,False}]
But sometimes I see that the order of the IP address and the bool getting changed.
this is the code

```
def createIpSet(ipFile):
    ipList = []
    ipFile = ipFile.read().splitlines()
    for lines in ipFile:
        s = set()
        s.add(lines)
        s.add(False)
        ipList.append(s)
    print(ipList)   
    return ipList
```

this is an example of the output

```
[{False, '192.168.1.1'}, {False, '192.168.1.2'}, {'192.168.1.3', False}, {'192.168.1.3', False}, {'192.168.1.4', False}, {False, '127.0.0.1'}, {False, '52.230.85.180'}, {False, '53.27.2.1'}, {False, '52.230.84.0'}]
```

as you can see for example in the third value inside the set - order is switched and I don't know why.
I would like you to explain why it is happening.
Thanks,
Omri.

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? If so, please consider accepting (green tick on left), so other users know.

Answer (score 3):

[Sets are unordered.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) You cannot and should not expect the output of a set to be printed in a particular order.

What you want is a list of tuples:

```
def createIpSet(ipFile):
    ipList = []
    ipFile = ipFile.read().splitlines()
    for lines in ipFile:
        ipList.append((lines, False))
    print(ipList)   
    return ipList
```

A list of lists is equally possible via `[lines, False]`. The main difference between `list` and `tuple` are lists are mutable while tuples are immutable.

Comment: In this case it looks like a `tuple` is wanted, judging by the diagram and their use of the immutable `set`.

Answer (score 0):

Sets are unordered as they use a hash function to insert the items into it .
You may use a dictionary representing ips as keys and bool values as a vaules.
It will look like

```
{'192.168.1.3': False, '192.168.1.4' : False }
```

The advantage of using dictionary vs lists of tuples is that the search or looking for an ip will take O(1) time vs O(n) for lists of tuples .

```
def createIpSet(ipFile):
    ipList = {}
    ipFile = ipFile.read().splitlines()
    for lines in ipFile:
        ipList[lines] =  False
    for ip ,value in ipList :
        print('Ip : {} ,value : {} '.format(ip , value))
    return ipList
```

In a pythonic way using comprehension :

```
def createIpSet(ipFile):
    ipList = {ip:False for ip in ipFile.read().splitlines()}
    for ip ,value in ipList :
        print('Ip : {} ,value : {} '.format(ip , value))
    return ipList
```

If you want to keep the order of ips as the file you can use OrderedDict .